# Grant privileges to a specific table with PostgreSQL (relation "*" does not exist)

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to grant read only access to a user on a few tables.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
postgres=# CREATE ROLE myuser LOGIN PASSWORD 'mypassword';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO myuser;
GRANT
```

The tests I have tried (which does not work):

```
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mytable TO myuser;
ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mydb.mytable TO myuser;
ERROR:  schema "mydb" does not exist
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE public.mytable TO myuser;
ERROR:  relation "public.mytable" does not exist
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mydb.public.mytable TO myuser;
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "mydb.public.mytable"
```

The resources I relied on:

https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/04/postgresql-how-to-create-read-only-user.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html

I do not understand what is missing because I followed these articles, my logic would be to specify in which database is the table but this is not mentioned.

I have also already checked for similar issues on StackOverflow, but the steps are the same as the resources I mentioned above.

(I don't know if it's relevant but I use postgresql 9.6)

Help would be really appreciated!

**============**

**EDIT:** when I run the \d command

```
postgres=# \d
No relations found.

postgres=# select current_database();
 current_database 
------------------
 postgres
(1 row)
```

I tought the postgres user had all the privileges, but maybe I should connect with my own user ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the output of the `\d` command. You are probably simply connected to the wrong database. Did you connect to `mydb`?   You can verify you current database using `select current_database();`

Comment: Yes it seems I am connected to the wrong database, I did not know I had to connect to `mydb` before in order to grant my access. Thank you for pointing me to the good track! It seems I only need to know how to connect to `mydb` now before granting my privileges.

Comment: You were right, after connecting to my database (`\c mydb`) I was able to run my commands without any worries, thank you! Do you want me to mark your answer as accepted?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In order to specify permissions on a particular table, you have to be connected to the relevant database.
You can connect to a database using the `\connect` or the `\c` command.

The following work:

```
postgres=# \connect mydb
postgres=# GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mytable TO myuser;
```

Useful commands:

- Verify your current database: `select current_database();`
- Check the available relations: `\d`

Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for pointing out the error.

Comment: I'm still getting the an ERROR:  permission denied for relation table when I try to GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mytable TO myuser; Do you know why this is happening. (It happens on GAppEngine Posgres9.6 using the public address and accessing through the terminal: psql (9.6.17, server 9.6.16)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.3, cipher: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
You are now connected to database ...)